# git corrupted on ubuntu vbox, power failure with proper shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, git, power, shutdown

i use git on ubuntu headless server on virtualbox on my laptop. 
when i shut down the pc, i don't bother shutting down the virtualbox, i just shutdown the pc.
it never was a problem.
it was fine since yesterday, when the power is gone. laptop had 2 hours remaining so i used it to the last minute, then i closed my ssh session, then closed the laptop. it properly closed, though power was out.
morning, when i opened the laptop again, git was corrupted.
why did this happen?

Comment: there can be any number of reasons why this happened.. if your virtualbox was processing data when the power was removed, all sorts of unexpected corruption can occur. I would recommend using better practices rather than wondering why bad practices have failed you every 1/5 times.

Comment: I eventually have to shutdown the pc anyway why should i explicitly state that. I just make sure i saved all my files before shutting down the pc, so why would that be bad practice or cause of a corruption, huh?

Comment: My git repository in the VM often gets corrupted even with proper shutdown of the VM. Has anybody opened an issue with virtualbox? e.g. https://liucs.net/cs102f13/non-virtual.html

Comment: I'm experiencing the very same problem, when I shut down the VM , my local repository gets corrupted.  The last commit gets trunkated to a zero length object.  As if the object file is being held open by git.

Comment: I'm still having these issues - running latest Virtual Box and latest Git on Windows 10. The description from @MartinSpamer matches what I observe. Anyone found a good work-around to avoid these problems?